# print the value of column which has the maximum decimal point

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max, precision

this is my dataframe:

```
     col1       col2
0    12.13      13.13
1    100.133    12.19994
2    11.16664   140.13
3    9.13       2.13
4    3.23       10.13
```

Now i want the column value which has the maximum decimal point length.

```
**OUTPUT:**
     maximum_de_point
**COL1** 11.16664
**COL2** 12.19994
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

col1 = [
    12.13,
    100.133,
    11.16664,
    9.13,
    3.23
]

col2 = [
    13.13,
    12.19994,
    140.13,
    2.13,
    10.13
]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([col1, col2]).T, columns=['col1','col2'])

# decimal lengths of col1
len1 = df['col1'].astype('str').apply(lambda a: len(a.split('.')[1]))

# decimal lengths of col2
len2 = df['col2'].astype('str').apply(lambda a: len(a.split('.')[1])) 

# get value at that index
col1_max = df['col1'][len1[len1 == max(len1)].index].tolist()[0]
col2_max = df['col2'][len2[len2 == max(len2)].index].tolist()[0]
```

Comment: thanks!1 that works fine..good idea...was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

One option is splitting the values with `str.split`, taking the `str.len` of the decimal part and finding the [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) of each column. Then [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) with the resulting values:

```
df_ixmax = df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.split('.').str[1].str.len()).idxmax(0)
df_ixmax[:] =df.lookup(*df_ixmax.reset_index().values[:,::-1].T)

df_ixmax
col1    11.16664
col2    12.19994
dtype: float64
```

Or we could also use [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html), which enables to obtain a count of the decimal places through the returned named tuple by `as_tuple()`, and then index the dataframe similarly to above from the result:

```
from decimal import Decimal 

ix = [[Decimal(str(x)).as_tuple().exponent for x in col] for col in df.values.T]
max_vals = df.values[np.array(ix).argmin(1), np.arange(df.shape[1])]
pd.Series(max_vals, index=df.columns)

col1    11.16664
col2    12.19994
dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks !! it was very helpful